# Convert Azure index Search result to json format data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am fairly new to Azure search. While learning about it, I am wondering if it is possible to Convert the search result into a json formatted data(even if it is a complex one). So far, I have tried the following and was able to map it to a object.

```
parameters = new SearchParameters()
            {
                OrderBy = new[]{"companyName desc"},
                Facets = new []{"companyName"}

            };
using (var client = _azureSearchClientFactory.GetAzureIndexClientForAllAdverts())
{
    client.Documents.Search<AdvertDetail>("Oslo", parameters);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to serialize the search results to JSON? If you're using Json.NET this page describes how to do that: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: Ok will try :) thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to covert the object to json string. As Yahnoosh mentioned that we could use the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object)` to do that easily.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);
```